# calculate the max length of an array such that average is less than given value

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, priority-queue

I've beern trying to solve this question but getting timeout for most test cases. Can anyone help me in optimising this?

Problem Statement :

You are given an array A of length N. You have to choose a subset S from given array A, such that average of S is less than K. You need to print the maximum possible length of S.

Input format :

```
The first line of each input contains  N, length of array A.
Next line contains N space separated elements of array A.
Next line of input contains an integer Q, Number of queries.
Each following Q  lines contains a single integer K.
```

Output format :

```
For each query, print single integer denoting the maximum possible length of the subset.
```

Sample Input

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Sample Output

```
0
2
4
5
5
```

Explanation

1. In first query, there is no possible subset such that its average is less than 1.
2. In second query, you can select the subset {1,2}.
3. In third query, you can select the subset {1,2,3,4}.
4. In fourth and fifth query, you can seelct the complete array {1,2,3,4,5}.

Here's my solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Playground {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = Long.parseLong(s.nextLine());                 // Reading input from STDIN
        String[] temp = s.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
        long[] arr = new long[(int) n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
        long q = Long.parseLong(s.nextLine());

        long[] queries = new long[(int) q];
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            long x = Long.parseLong(s.nextLine());
            queries[i] = x;
        }
        PriorityQueue<Long> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        for (long x : arr)
            queue.add(x);
        for (long x : queries) {
            double avg = 0;
            List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
            int i = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            boolean flag = false;
            while (! queue.isEmpty()) {
                long num = queue.poll();
                i++;
                list.add(num);
                sum += num;
                avg = (double) sum / i;

                if (avg >= x) {
                    System.out.println(i - 1);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (! flag)
                System.out.println(n);
            queue.addAll(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Curious:* If you know that `n` and `q` needs to fit in an `int`, why are you using `parseLong` instead of `parseInt`?

Comment: Yes you are right. we can ignore that.

Comment: Don't use a `PriorityQueue` that you have to keep re-building. Just sort the array once, then re-use it for each query. --- Also, `double` division is much slower than `long` multiplication, so `if ((double) sum / i >= x)` should be rewritten as `if (sum >= x * i)`. --- Don't know if these two hints will bring enough performance gains to complete task on time. You'll have to try it and see.

Comment: I never saw the point in selecting a problem from a challenge site and then having someone else solve it. My problem, not yours. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to solve this is to sort the array first.
After you sorted the array so each element is equal or greater than the last, then solving a single run is easy:

```
int count = 0;
int limit = 0;
for (int i : sortedArray) {
    int diff = i - maxAvg;
    if (limit + diff < 0) {
        limit += diff;
        count++
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

This works because if the difference to the max average is negative you can use values with a positive difference until you hit the limit.

Sorting the array is `O(n*log(n))`, and for each solution you only need `O(n)`

This is my full solution with all the parsing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arrLen = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    int[] array = new int[arrLen];
    String[] strNums = sc.nextLine().split(" ", arrLen);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNums[i]);
    }

    Arrays.sort(array);

    int numTests = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++) {
        int maxAvg = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        int limit = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int j : array) {
            int diff = j - maxAvg;
            if (limit + diff < 0) {
                count++;
                limit += diff;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: Only picking numbers that are below the average will not find answer `[1,2]` (average=1.5) for `k=2`.

Comment: Thanks, I made a small mistake. But I don't just pick numbers below the average. In your example, after the first round, `limit` is `-1`. `(-1) + 0` is `< 0`, so it will be picked too.